# How i can connect Openvpn Client by C#

Tags: c#, winforms, openvpn, openvpn-connect

Xingcode have to anti OpenvpnDeamon
Is there a way for me to be able to connect directly without going through  a third party By Config.ovpn not private account?

windowsapplication
winform
C#